# Typing master password of pass wrong

Tags: gnupg, password-recovery

I have successfully setup [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) with a gpg key.
When I ask for a stored password I see a counter for three attempts.
My first question is what happens after three attempts?
Does it only add a timeout, or do I lose access to my stored passwords?

My second quesion is: can I increase the threshold to another/higher number?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it only add a timeout, or do I lose access to my stored passwords?

I tested it on a fresh `pass` repository and typing the wrong password three times only stops the login. One can immediately try again to login. Access to passwords etc. is not lost.

Hence increasing the number of attempts is not really necessary.